# how to define "\n" as enl or anything in vscode cpp.json user snippet/ boilerplate

Tags: boilerplate, vscode-snippets

i am trying to define "\n" in my cpp.json file which is the boilerplate for cpp and when i define it like "#define enl '\n'", and use it in my code, instead of getting #define enl '\n'
i literally get a newline printed in my code.
like:

```
#define enl '
'
```

is there any way to solve this?

full code:

```
{
    "CPP": {
            "prefix": "Bcc",
            "body": [
                "#include <iostream>",
                "#define ll long long int",
                "#define enl '\n'",
                "using namespace std;",
                "void solve(){}",
                "int main(){",
                "    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);",
                "    cin.tie(nullptr);",
                "    int tc = 1;",
                "    cin >> tc;",
                "    for (int t = 1; t <= tc; t++) {",
                "        solve();",
                "    }",
                "    return 0;",
                "}",
            ],
            "description": "Log output to console"
    }
}
```

i tried with both #define and typedef but it doesnot work. while if i write it manually like #define enl '\n' without using the boiler plate, it works fine like it should.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the \ by typing them as \\ instead?

Comment: @Holo yess it worked perfectly fine, thank you, i did not know about the escape thing.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to answer your own question if you want, and mark your solution as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while trying to use "#define enl '\n'" in usersnippet we can use
`\\` instead of `\` to escape the `\` that is causing to print a newline.
Thanks to @Holo for the Help :) .